# cannot build mariadb C connector with mingw

Tags: c, mingw, mariadb, connector

After using command:
cmake.exe -G "MinGW Makefiles"

lots and lots of headers are not found.

-- Looking for include file alloca.h

-- Looking for include file alloca.h - not found

-- Looking for include file arpa/inet.h

-- Looking for include file arpa/inet.h - not found

-- Looking for include file crypt.h

-- Looking for include file crypt.h - not found

-- Looking for include file dirent.h

-- Looking for include file dirent.h - found

-- Looking for include file dlfcn.h

-- Looking for include file dlfcn.h - not found

-- Looking for include file execinfo.h

-- Looking for include file execinfo.h - not found

................
................
errors continue
...............

and of course, when running mingw32-make, errors appear.

is there any cmake flag missing?

Comment: I'm using:gcc (i686-posix-sjlj-rev1, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 6.2.0
cmake version 3.9.3

Answer (score 0):

I have built the MariaDB C Connector with mingw.
I don't know if this will work in your environment
(in fact it's not utterly clear what your environment is),
but it will work in this environment:
Windows 10, gcc i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, MinGW 5.3.0 (the one that came with Qt 5.9),
MariaDB source download for 2.2.3.
That MariaDB version number is important: avoid version 3.0.2.
You have to change the source file libmariadb\my_pthread.c
to avoid duplicate-function messages, this is not hard:
the "#ifdef WIN32" before the functions should be changed to
something impossible, e.g. "#ifdef WIN32_IMPOSSIBLE".
Then (I'm running from the directory that contains CMakeLists.txt,
I didn't try shadow building): mingw32-make clean, then
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles", then mingw32-make.
Yes, cmake says "not found" a bunch of times, and mingw32-make
generates warnings, but the result is
an .a file in the libmariadb subdirectory, and I've successfully
linked to it in my project.